# WAMP Server can't be accessed from WiFi Devices

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wamp

I had setup a WAMP server in Windows 10, I have configured it to access from WAN. And also I have configured the Firewall, Now the `localhost` page can be accessed from WAN & wired LAN. But if I use a laptop, smartphone connected through Wi-Fi on the same network, I can’t access the `localhost` page. All PC’s and smartphones are in the same network `192.168.1.0/24`.

With my smartphone I could access the `localhost` page by entering the Public IP address of the site in the browser. But I couldn’t access not with the private IP `192.168.1.10` of the server.

Comment: Can you ping the server from the wifi connected device/s?

Comment: cant ping but all devices are in same network 192.168.1.0 getting host unreachable reply while pinging

Comment: It is a different issue then. You will not be able to acess any server on the laptop until ping succeeds. Try the solutions here: http://superuser.com/questions/453933/pinging-a-machine-on-my-local-network-gets-an-unreachable-response-from-my-own

Comment: i found it the issue is in the router's setup. This link solves me
http://chandamama.blogspot.in/2013/10/cantpingotherdevicesonlandlink.
html