# I cannot Ping any IP or Web address only on my machine running Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping

For a few days, I have noticed that I cannot ping any Local IP from the network, only on my Laptop from Asus. When I open `CMD` then type `ping 192.168.1.1` or `ping 8.8.8.8` (Google DNS), I don't get any respond (as it is shown on the screenshot below), like unreachable or anything else.

![ping][1]

Also I have tried to ping any website live on the Internet, the result is same. I do have internet access and I thought this could be the problem from the Modem. So therefore I have reset the modem to it's default settings. But unfortunately there is no improvement.

I have done the same test mentioned above on my old Vaio Laptop also running Windows 10 and the result was fine.

Is there any suggestion that will help resolve this issue?

Comment: A screen shot would help us understand your question.
StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please have a thorough look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/453933/pinging-a-machine-on-my-local-network-gets-an-unreachable-response-from-my-own) to see if its answers can be of any help. If not, try disabling the Windows Firewall (or any other firewall you may have) for a short while and run the `ping` command again.

Comment: Can you verify that your local ip address is 192.168.1.x? (the x one doesn't matter, the rest does) and please confirm that the subnetmask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Actually am Using DHCP. 192.168.1.1 is the Default getaway.

Comment: Please post the output of the command "ipconfig -all". Point out the name of the LAN interface used.

Comment: Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 48-51-B7-6A-64-1E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Comment: Please find more here http://imgur.com/xjf7dok

Comment: Network settings are 100% correct. You should be able to ping 192.168.1.1 as your notebook already has successfully contacted this address for DHCP. Next, I would disable IPv6 on this adapter, your router and/or ISP will probably not support it but your notebook might use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issue has bee resolved successfully by the following:

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type Command prompt, right-click (or press and hold) Command prompt, and then select Run as administrator > Yes.
2. At the command prompt, run the following commands in the listed order, and then check to see if that fixes your connection problem:
   Type netsh winsock reset and press Enter.
   Type netsh int ip reset and press Enter.
   Type ipconfig /release and press Enter.
   Type ipconfig /renew and press Enter.
   Type ipconfig /flushdns and press Enter.
   Hope the information helps. Do reply if you need further assistance.

Comment: This worked for me, after a restart I had to reset my IP as it had defaulted back to auto, but after this I was then able to access my LAN again.  Before this I got the error: "General Failure" when I tried to ping any ip address including the my own.  It would ping 127.0.0.1 but not my 192.168.X.X address or any other 192.168.X.X address on the network.  Thanks for sharing the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if any of the websites used CloudFlare DDoS protection.
Websites with the security do not let you ping the websites.

Comment: (1) OP is getting different results from different (client) machines, so the problem can’t be (entirely) on the server end.   (2) 8.8.8.8 is pingable.