# Why can't I access a Linux machine remotely from my windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, putty, cygwin, ping

I want to connect from windows 10 to an external Linux server remotely. I tried Putty and Cygwin's Mintty. Neither of them works.

I then went to Windows Defender Firewall and unblocked those two applications. However, that didn't work either.

I then uninstalled all the antivirus and Windows system management tools like Malwarebytes and IOBit tools.

Then after much investigation, I discovered that I can't ping Google or any other website from my Windows 10 machine, but I am able to browse them via the web browsers.

[image]

Then, I tried these instructions:

- https://superuser.com/a/1074532/1047573

that didn't work either.

So, kindly tell me what is going on in my PC, and how can I access a Linux machine remotely from my machine?

Comment: There is a complete lack of any useful information given to help troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: @Keltari, kindly tell me what information I should supply.

Comment: try disablying the Firewall totally and than check again with ping. Mintty is not a client ssh program so unblocking it makes no difference