# Ping not working between Laptop and Phone even with firewall rules and without firewall

Tags: windows, ping

I have three devices in my LAN. Laptop, PC and Phone. I am trying to ping my Laptop from Phone and vice versa, but I get the `Destination host unreachable` each time.

I have added and enabled firewall rules in Windows firewall to allow for ICMPv4 traffic both in- and outbound but it didn't help. I have even disabled the firewall, to no avail.

The issue is complicated by the fact that ping works basically between all other devices, wired or wireless, in the network, just not between my laptop and phone. (see full overview of network with detailed info below)

Here is ping output from my Laptop to phone:
[image]

As an asides question, why is there 0% loss when it says it can't even reach the destination?

My main question: How can I fix the problem so that ping works between my Laptop and Phone.

**Info on Network and firewall**

- Network layout:  `PC <==ETH==>  ROUTER  <- WLAN ->  Laptop, Phone`
- My Laptop IP Address is `192.168.178.44`, connected via WLAN
- My Phone IP Address is `192.168.178.69`, connected via WLAN
- My PC IP Address is `192.168.178.10`, connected via Ethernet
- Ping works between PC and Phone, and PC and Laptop in both directions each. For example here I am pinging my PC from the Laptop
  [image]
- Ping doesn't work between Laptop and Phone, in neither direction
- I have even disabled my firewall and it didn't make a change
  [image]
- Yes my network profile is set as private
  [image]

---

Note: This question differs from [that one](https://superuser.com/questions/453933/pinging-a-machine-on-my-local-network-gets-an-unreachable-response-from-my-own?rq=1) even though they sound similar at first glance in following ways:

- That other question is about why the `Destination host unreachable` message is sent from the device sending the message
- There the top answer talks about a router setting that prevents wired <-> wireless communication. This is clearly not the case here as PC and Phone can communicate flawlessly, just Laptop and Phone cant, which are both wireless

Comment: Have you tried temporarily disabling the firewall entirely then checking?  Maybe the rules you setup are not being processed or are incorrect.

Comment: @kicken Thanks for your question, I have updated my question with various infos. I am seriously having trouble fixing this and am utterly at a loss of why it doesn't work.

Comment: The linked QA also mentions a setting to isolate wireless clients from each other, not just wired-wireless.  Check your router for such a setting, possibly named something like "Isolate Clients"

Comment: @kicken Excellent! I read this *There's also a setting called AP isolation, which prevents communication between **wired and wireless** clients* and understood it to not mean wireless <-> wireless, rather just wired <-> wireless, so I didn't think that was it. But I found a similar setting in my router settings and it fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a check box called "Allow WLAN devices to communicate with each other" in my router settings which was turned off.

Enabling that fixed the issue.